# How to make SoftwareSerial variable available in a function in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to make use of a SoftwareSerial variable in a function, but for some reason it is always unavailable.
The various codes are given below.

```
gsm.h

#ifndef GSM_H_
#define GSM_H_
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

struct gsm{

    char *message;
    char phone_number[20];

    void getText(SoftwareSerial serial, int index);
};


#endif


gsm.cpp

#include "gsm.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void gsm::getText(SoftwareSerial serial, int index){

    char str[100];
    serial.print("AT+CMGR=1 \r");
    delay(250);
    if(serial.available()){
       Serial.print("serial is available");
       serial.readBytes(message, 100);
    }

}


test.ino

#include "gsm.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

gsm gm;

void setup(){

   Serial.begin(9600);
   mySerial.begin(9600);
   gm.getText(mySerial,1);
   Serial.print(gm.message);
}

void loop(){

}
```

**Serial.print(gm.message)** is supposed to return what has been copied into message by **serial.readBytes(message,100)**. 
But it seems the test for serial availability failed as the code inside **if(serial.available())** don't get executed. Please i need help as i have been battling with this for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
if (mySerial.available()>0){
   mySerial.read();
}
```

Comment: its not available either@stackmalux

Comment: try this simple example to test SoftwareSerial with serial [https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialExample]

Comment: It's working when implemented that way, but that's not what am trying to do.

Comment: have you try it inside the loop?